# How to access the dropped element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using draggable with the connectToSortable and clone option with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SGevw/):

```
var draggable_opts = {
        connectToSortable: ".sph-callout-portlet",
        helper: "clone",
        opacity: 0.75,
        revert: 'invalid',
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            // this seems to only access the original item not the clone
        }
    };

$(function() {
    $( ".sph-callout-portlet" ).sortable({
        opacity: 0.75,
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    }).disableSelection();

    $( "#sph-callout-portlet-avail li" ).draggable(draggable_opts);

});
```

When I drop the element, I want to get the ID of the area it was dropped into or at least the element itself. Now, according to the docs `draggable + connectToSortable + clone` uses `droppable` but I can't see a way to get the dropped element.

(The above code originally was posted in a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626108/jquery-ui-draggable-sortable-dynamically-added-items-not-draggable) with a different problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the element in which it was dropped , you could do:

```
$(".sph-callout-portlet" ).sortable({
   opacity: 0.75,
   placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
   receive: function(event, ui) {
     console.log($(this).data().sortable.element);
   }
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: So far I'm getting this 'monster': `console.log($(this).data().sortable.element.context.id);` giving me the id of the parent! Does that make sense or is there a better way? (it does work after all)

Comment: @Gazzer there might be a better way, which i'm not aware of, but this seems to work without any problem..

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate a [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) on your droppable areas:

```
$(area_selector).droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var $area = $(this); // The droppable
        var $draggable = ui.draggable; // The draggable
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried something like this before but couldn't get it to work. Could you be specific about area_selector in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $( "#sph-callout-portlet-avail li" ).droppable({
     drop: function (event, ui) {
       console.log(ui.draggable.text());
     }
 });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SGevw/36/) here

Comment: This would get the text but not the element itself. So I wouldn't be able to get where the element has been dropped.